# Parsing Steam trade offer error codes to console

Tags: c#, steam, steam-web-api

I'm using CSharpTradeOffers library ([GitHub](https://github.com/FatherFoxxy/CSharpTradeOffers))

So there are

SendTradeOfferWithLink (CSharpTradeOffers/Trading/EconServiceHandler.cs)
and SendOfferResponse (CSharpTradeOffers/Trading/Data Classes/SendOfferResponse.cs) functions.

Basically I have this code:

```
TradeOffer offer = new TradeOffer();
offer.Me.Assets.Add(csgoInventory.Items.First().Value.Items.First().ToCEconAsset(730));
offerHandler.SendTradeOfferWithLink(steamid, token, msg, "1", offer, _account.AuthContainer);
```

But if trade offer was failed because of error — I can't see anything in console. Can anyone explain me, please, how can I output trade offer error code (e.g. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGX6O.jpg)) to console if trade offer was not made?
There's even JsonProperty("strError"), but I can't understand how can I parse this error string to console.

Hopefully, someone understood my language :D Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`SendTradeOfferWithLink` returns a `SendOfferResponse` which has the `Error` that you can write to the console :

```
TradeOffer offer = new TradeOffer();
offer.Me.Assets.Add(csgoInventory.Items.First().Value.Items.First().ToCEconAsset(730));
var response = offerHandler.SendTradeOfferWithLink(steamid, token, msg, "1", offer, _account.AuthContainer);

Console.WriteLine(response.Error);
```

*If that error message is not in the desired format, update your question with that error.

Comment: response.Error is null somehow, but I'm sure there is an error